# Is Sunshine dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, harold-and-maude

It isn't completely clear from the film "Harold and Maude" whether the actress called "Sunshine", the third computer-selected partner for Harold, really inflicted deadly injuries to herself with the Harakiri knife after Harold enacted his suicide, or whether she was acting as well - just better than Harold.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4):

No. According to the script, [here](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Harold-and-Maude.htm) Sunshine 'knew' Harold was acting, in fact asking him who he trained with. She takes the knife and plays with the blade to determine how it works (slide up into the handle) and then proceeds to 'kill herself' using it (the acting prop knife) while continuing to act out Romeo and Juliet's Juliet death scene.